# taking damage in combos (health) as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want the combo to take away 30 health. I have made the combo and it works, I just don't know the code to take away. as3

```
function checkCombo(e:KeyboardEvent){
            if(comboActivating){
                trace("combo checkign");
                if(e.keyCode==combo[comboindex]){
                    comboindex++;
                }
                else{
                    comboindex=0;
                    trace("combo reset");
                    comboActivating=false;
                }
                if(comboindex==combo.length){
                    trace("combo completes");
                }

            }else{
                    if(e.keyCode==combo[comboindex]){
                        trace("combo activating");
                        comboActivating=true;
                        comboindex++;
                    }
                }
                this.health-=30;

        }
```

Is this where I add it? All of the combo stuff works but I'm still unsure on the health. Please help.

Comment: You have only provided  some information. We have no context as to what your expected result should be. With that said, based on what you have provided I can tell you that 30 will be subtracted from the `health` of `this` (whatever that is) every time `checkCombo` is called. If you want it to subtract when combo completes, then you need to put it up where that trace statement is located.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the code is in the right parameters you would have to move this.health-=30; inside the if statement that checks the combo.

```
if(comboActivating){
            trace("combo checkign");
            if(e.keyCode==combo[comboindex]){
                this.health-=30;
                comboindex++;
            }
```

If this doesn't work you will need to provide more information.